# Start Google's restore activity, but it shows always in dark theme

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing a customized setup wizard in Android 5.0+. After google login, I call google's restore activity by following codes, but the restore activity always shows "dark" theme, not "light" as other google page.
Did I miss something?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.google.android.setupwizard.RESTORE");
Bundle options = new Bundle(); 
options.putBoolean("useImmersiveMode", true);
options.putBoolean("setupWizard", true);
options.putString("theme", "material_light");
intent.putExtras(options);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESTORE_CODE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CyanogenMod's method of adding:

```
options.putString("scriptUri", "android.resource://com.google.android.setupwizard/xml/wizard_script");
```

It works, but then the activity crashes when going to the next screen, there's probably a way around it, but I haven't looked into it.